# Android Espresso Test Fails When Calling `ActivityScenario.onActivity`

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

When I try to run the following test, my Activity launches, but the View is never shown (it's just a black screen), then it times out and fails. If I remove the call to `activityRule.doOnFirstFragment` it passes fine.

I can see that the Activity started in logcat.

Anyone know why that call would make the test timeout?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MyActivityTest {
  @get:Rule
  internal var activityRule = activityScenarioRule<MyActivity>()

  private inline fun ActivityScenarioRule<*>.doOnFirstFragment(
      crossinline block: () -> Unit
  ) {
    scenario.onActivity {
      // replace this with code to determine that first fragment was loaded
      Thread.sleep(2000)

      block()
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun canEnterPhoneNumber() {
    activityRule.doOnFirstFragment {
      onView(withText("Get Started"))
          .perform(click())
      onView(withText("Request PIN"))
          .check(matches(not(isEnabled())))
      onView(withHint("Phone Number"))
          .perform(typeText("5555555555"), closeSoftKeyboard())
      onView(withText("Request PIN"))
          .check(matches(isEnabled()))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `onActivity` runs on the main thread. Are you actually doing blocking work within that method?

Comment: Oh interesting. I'm calling the espresso matcher functions in that scope. Would they not work on the main thread?